# How to get the parent from the click event of button in the control template?

Tags: wpf

Usercontrol has the below control template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MarkerTemplate"  >
        <ToggleButton x:Name="btnMarkerPin" Click="btnMarkerPin_Click" >
            <ToggleButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Fill="Green" Width="25" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ToolTip="{Binding}" />
        </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.Template>               
        </ToggleButton>
```

By btnMarkerPin_Click event i can get the togglebutton object as sender , but requirement is to get the parent object to which this template is applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var templatedParent = ((ToggleButton)sender).TemplatedParent;
```

Comment: I was using the `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent()` to get the `ContentPresenter` and this is by far more readable (and probably more performance-wise, as I don't need a recursive loop anymore). Thanks.